# Utilizing OLE in Go results in "The tag is invalid" error

Tags: go, window, ole

I am attempting to utilize OLE in go to set the default audio output source on Windows 10. I am using 2 third-party packages to accomplish this:

- https://github.com/go-ole/go-ole
- https://github.com/moutend/go-wca

The problem that I am having is that the function `pcv.SetDefaltEndpoint()` is not setting the default output source but is instead returning an error that simply says `The tag is invalid`.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "syscall"
    "unsafe"

    "github.com/go-ole/go-ole"
    "github.com/moutend/go-wca/pkg/wca"
)

type IPolicyConfig struct {
    ole.IUnknown
}

type IPolicyConfigVtbl struct {
    ole.IUnknownVtbl
    GetDeviceFormat       uintptr
    ResetDeviceFormat     uintptr
    SetDeviceFormat       uintptr
    GetProcessingPeriod   uintptr
    SetProcessingPeriod   uintptr
    GetShareMode          uintptr
    SetShareMode          uintptr
    GetPropertyValue      uintptr
    SetPropertyValue      uintptr
    SetDefaultEndpoint    uintptr
    SetEndpointVisibility uintptr
}

func (v *IPolicyConfig) VTable() *IPolicyConfigVtbl {
    return (*IPolicyConfigVtbl)(unsafe.Pointer(v.RawVTable))
}

func (v *IPolicyConfig) SetDefaultEndpoint(deviceID string, eRole wca.ERole) (err error) {
    err = pcvSetDefaultEndpoint(v, deviceID, eRole)
    return
}

func pcvSetDefaultEndpoint(pcv *IPolicyConfig, deviceID string, eRole wca.ERole) (err error) {
    var ptr *uint16
    if ptr, err = syscall.UTF16PtrFromString(deviceID); err != nil {
        return
    }

    hr, _, _ := syscall.SyscallN(
        pcv.VTable().SetDefaultEndpoint,
        3,
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(pcv)),
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(ptr)),
        uintptr(uint32(eRole)))
    if hr != 0 {
        err = ole.NewError(hr)
    }
    return
}

func main() {
    if err := ole.CoInitializeEx(0, ole.COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED); err != nil {
        return
    }
    defer ole.CoUninitialize()

    CPolicyConfigClientUID := ole.NewGUID("870AF99C-171D-4F9E-AF0D-E63DF40C2BC9")
    IPolicyConfigUID := ole.NewGUID("F8679F50-850A-41CF-9C72-430F290290C8")

    var pcv *IPolicyConfig
    if err := wca.CoCreateInstance(CPolicyConfigClientUID, 0, wca.CLSCTX_ALL, IPolicyConfigUID, &pcv); err != nil {
        return
    }
    defer pcv.Release()

    fmt.Println(pcv.SetDefaultEndpoint("{0.0.0.00000000}.{81d9ff45-7f2a-4397-9885-0275cb01c816}", wca.EMultimedia))
}
```

I used the source code of this package (in C#) to confirm that the GUIDs and Device ID I'm supplying are correct but I'm still not having any luck.

https://github.com/sirWest/AudioSwitch

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you all for your time.

EDIT: I just now realized that I was using `syscall.SyscallN` incorrectly. It appears the old way of using it was to supply the number of arguments, but `syscallN` does not need this. After correcting this, I'm now getting this error: `A null reference pointer was passed to the stub.` despite all the variables being supplied to it are not null

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out! For the first uintptr in my struct I had the word `GetDeviceFormat` not `GetMixFormat`. I hope my pain and suffering helps somebody, even if it's 5 years in the future.